# questions about operator "&"

Tags: c, operators, int

Probably have wrong title,but I don't know how to describe it.

```
int x=0x4a;
h=!(0x80000000000&(0x39+(~x+1)));
```

the result is h=0.
The question is x has 32 bits, while 0x80000000000 has more than 32 bit. If I set variable i to 0x80000000000 and print it as hex format,it will show 0. So in that case, why not the result of h is 1 because 0x80000000000 turns to be 0?

The language I used is C

Comment: Please tag this question with what language this is.

Comment: Tag with language, and then show the code that you refer to in your last paragraph.

Comment: @tpaksu For this to work in C as the OP describes, h must be a 32 bit integer, i.e. an `int` or a `long int`.

Comment: @Dmitri Chubarov, Im' sorry but I have rejected your edit(retag as C and declare h as int) as OP has not confirmed them. People will start answering assuming OP has confirmed about the language and type. Your guess about them may be correct, but if not then there could be different problems. So please wait for OP before doing such drastic edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x8000000000 is a `long long int` constant. Therefore the C compiler promotes the types in an arithmetic expression to the highest precision that occurs within an expression.

If instead you wrote:

```
  int x=0x4a;
  int h1=(0x80000000000&(0x39+(~x+1)));
  int h = !h1;
```

Then `h` would become 1. And perhaps a warning on missing precision would be issued.