# Questions about operator "+"

Tags: c, operators

The language I use is C.

I have code as follows:

```
int sign_x=~(x>>31)+1;
int sign_y=~(y>>31)+1;
int sign=sign_x^sign_y;
return ((!sign)&(!(!(0x80000000&(y+(~x+1)))))+(sign&(!sign_x)));
```

When I set input x=2147483647[0x7fffffff],y=-2147483648[0x80000000],the result is 0.
I wonder why the result is 0 rather than 1 because the first part is 0 and the second part is 1.When I changed operator "+" to "|",the result is OK.

Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: **What language**?

Comment: Dude, you were asked about the language [the previous time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862523/questions-about-operator) as well. The answer depends on what programming language you use so you need to tell it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 + 1 *is* 1, which means that the operator precedence is different than what you thought it is.

gcc is clever enough to emit a warning for this:

> warning: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ in operand of ‘&’

```
(!sign) & (!(!(0x80000000&(y+(~x+1)))))+(sign&(!sign_x)));
```

add extra parentheses:

```
((!sign)&(!(!(0x80000000&(y+(~x+1)))))) + ((sign&(!sign_x))));
```

or, since the expression is quite complex, temporarily store parts of the result:

```
int part1 = ...
int part2 = ...
return part1 + part2;
```

Comment: does the operator "&" have higher priority than operator "+"?

Comment: @Shirley: No. The information is available in any decent C literature. [Here](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html) for example.

Answer (score 2):

It is for operator precedence you need to add parentheses:

```
int funcTest(int x, int y) {

int sign_x=~(x>>31)+1;
int sign_y=~(y>>31)+1;
int sign=sign_x^sign_y;
return (
 ((!sign)&(!(!(0x80000000&(y+(~x+1)))))) + (sign&(!sign_x))
);
```

Return 1 .

See the parentheses that are around the first part of the sum :

```
(!sign)&(!(!(0x80000000&(y+(~x+1))))) ----> ((!sign)&(!(!(0x80000000&(y+(~x+1))))))
```